# mv a folder and now the folder seems gone

Tags: command-line, bash

I typed the following:

```
mv /var/www/folder/ ../../
```

Now I can't find that folder or anything that was inside of it. What am I missing?

/var looks like this:

```
root@,my-server:/var# ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root   4096 Apr 28 11:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root   4096 Apr 29 06:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May  3 06:53 backups
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root   4096 Apr 29 06:48 cache
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Apr 28 11:17 crash
drwxr-xr-x 46 root root   4096 Apr 29 06:48 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4096 Apr 10  2014 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Apr 28 09:33 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 14 root syslog 4096 May  3 06:53 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail   4096 May  1 06:34 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Feb 17 17:12 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Apr 28 09:33 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 Apr 28 16:28 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Apr 29 06:53 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 May  3 15:33 www
```

Comment: From which working directory did you run this command?

Comment: `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Comment: OMG, I get it. I found it there. Thank you @ByteCommander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`folder` is now located in the parent of the parent (`../..`) of the directory that was the current directory at time the `mv` command was executed.

If your intention was to move `folder` into `/var` you should have done:

```
mv /var/www/folder/ /var/www/folder/../../
```

Or simply

```
mv /var/www/folder/ /var/
```

To display current directory use `pwd`, for example

```
$ pwd
/home/jay/tmp/test

$ mv /var/www/folder/ ../../

$ ls -d ../../folder
../../folder
```

or equivalent

```
$ ls -d /home/jay/folder
/home/jay/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You moved your `/var/www/folder` to `../../`, but what des that mean?

`.` and `..` are special entries every directory has. The `.` references this directory itself while the `..` references the parent directory.

So `../../` is a relative path which points to the current working directory's "grand-parent" directory i.e. the directory two levels above your current one.

So as you ran the `mv` command in question from inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, you moved the other folder into the directory two levels above from this one, which is `/etc`.

Answer (score 0):

What it did is that it moved the source content to `../../` ( parent of parent). Mentioning the path of root directory of destination would have done the work for you but now it just moved all the content 2 directories before in hierarchy.

Comment: @TheBrownOne how does this not answer? As far as I can tell, this answer is explaining precisely what happened here.